# Why Is My Spreadsheet Showing Ghost Images From Another Worksheet After Running My Script

Tags: excel, vba

(07/08/21 - I edited my text to update and sharpen the problem).

I have made an Excel VBA program that provides the conditional formatting of a large number of cells (which are formatted using the formulas option which refer to cell values in the target spreadsheet). The script and spreadsheet works fine, but I have a problem as immediately after I have run my script (or to be precise a particular input box script has been run) then ghost images appears. (I can easily replicate the issue including on different Windows machines.) The ghost images no longer happen if the user saves the sheet and then re-opens it. However, to me this is not a good solution and makes the program look poor in quality and trustworthiness!

I have a "first" routine that when run (via a button press) uses an Application.Inputbox - this allows the user to select a range of cells. These selection of cells are located in the target worksheet which is a different workbook to where the code is run from. Also, the selection of cells are located in a sheet that is not the front sheet of the workbook concerned.

I then have another second button which when pressed uses collected data and conditionally formats the target spreadsheet. However, after doing this button press I get ghost images appearing (which shows cells from selection made earlier from the first button press).

The screenshot below illustrates the occurrence - you can see that there is a table being shown from the second sheet on the top left-hand side of the sheet (despite not fitting the cells of screen 1!). I hope that makes sense.

[image]

Someone kindly below said that I needed to use:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating=False
```

and then return it to true at the end.

However, I still have the same ghost images occur and I note these happen after the script has been run.

From researching the topic, I found that this is a common issue from using the property Application.InputBox. If I run my second program without using the first one immediately before it (which has the Application.InputBox) then no ghost images appear. Therefore, I think it is pretty safe to assume the problem has come from this Application.InputBox! However, I have not been able to find a solution! I list below the code used for the first Application.InputBoxs routine.

```
Sub UserSelectsCells()

Dim rng As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook
   
If Range("C9") <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("C9")
End If

On Error Resume Next
  Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
    Title:="Select Test Cells", _
    Prompt:="Please Find The Cells In Your Workbook That Test Whether The User Has Answered The Questions Correctly" & vbCrLf & "Remember this may be in a different sheet in your workbook" & vbCrLf & "These cells must be in a single column", _
    Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

'Test to ensure User Did not cancel
  If rng Is Nothing Then
    Workbooks("Version060821.xlsm").Activate
    Exit Sub
    End If

Workbooks("Version060821.xlsm").Activate
    
Range("C32").Value = rng.Parent.Parent.Name
Range("C33").Value = rng.Parent.Name
Range("C34").Value = rng.Address
Range("D35").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Range("D35").Value = rng.Count
End sub
```

Can anyone please find a solution? As an idea, is it possible to somehow clean the memory before my second program is run?

I note that if there is a ghost images problem and I delete all of the conditional formating then the ghost images still appear. I think this is significant because the conditional formatting is linked to the ghost image cells that appear. So, to me this suggests there is some kind of microsoft bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why these ghost screens pop up sometimes but I've found that preventing the screen from flashing during your code normally fixes the issue. You can do this by setting Application.ScreenUpdating to False and the beginning of your code. Just be sure to set it back to True at the end! Something like this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
[Your code]
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

edit:
After further research, it would appear this is an issue that has been already identified. The workaround below originally comes from [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/35399-redraw-screen/).

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim wSheet As Worksheet
   On Error Resume Next 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For Each wSheet In Worksheets
      wSheet.Select
      Range("A1").Select
   Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is definitely a dirty fix but if it works it works. An alternative solution was to scroll up and down using:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-100
   ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Up:=100
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please let me know what works best!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post. I gratefully tried your coding, but I still have the ghost screen appearing! Is there anything I can do to improve the chance of its success? Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! I did a bit of digging and it looks like others have had the issue. I added in two fixes that others suggested above. They both are workarounds that try to force the screen to update itself. Not ideal, but I hope one of these will solve the issue.

Comment: Ben Mega - thank you very much and well done! This certainly fixed my problem and I am please/relieved to state that the ghost images stop. Can you explain what the Cancel As Boolean actually does in the Workbook_BeforeClose ? When calling the routine does one need to set this as true or false?

Comment: Otherwise, to me this seems incredible that this issue with Ghost Images has been identified as far back as 2005 and is still an issue in 2021! Is this a reasonable statement to make or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The Workbook_BeforeClose event is triggered when the workbook is closed but there is the situation when a user clicks the X to close and then hits cancel.  This parameter allows control on whether or not to still run the code when that happens. You shouldn't have to call this routine but if you do I would keep Cancel False.

Comment: I suspect this is a niche issue that Microsoft has just decided is not worth dealing with. Sad but that's life sometimes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep for a comment!

Alec, Workbook_BeforeClose is a workbook event, you don't call it like procedures.

[Workbook_BeforeClose Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforeclose)

From that documentation, "*False when the event occurs. If the event procedure sets this argument to True, the close operation stops and the workbook is left open.*". So if you add `Cancel=True` inside it, say, after an if statement check, you can stop the close operation.

**Edit**: In order to answer the question in comments.

The event is fired when you close the workbook, either from the X in the corner or from the menu, or if you have something like `ActiveWorkbook.Close` in your code.

You don't have to have a Cancel=True/False inside BeforeClose event's code, depends on if you want to control a premature closure of the workbook. It is required, say, if you were writing the event yourself instead of selecting it in VBA editor. Editor already inserts that parameter.

Comment: Gokhan Aycan - thank you very much for posting. Sorry, I should have looked at the documentation before posting. I think from what you have written that I will stick with setting this argument to false when calling the script.